# Antergos Linux gnome3 powerbuttons disapeared

Tags: linux, shutdown, hibernate, reboot

I installed Antergos Linux a few days ago (sdb5). I'm new to Linux so I just used most the defaults (changed Chrome to Firefox) and used sdb8 as /home and sdb9 as swap.

I changed a few setting, reboot the system several times wondering why Windows10 (installed on a PCI-SSD) didn't show up in the boot manager, but everything else was working fine. I installed openSUSE with XFCE on sdb7 (again sdb8 = /home, sdb9 = swap) but didn't liked it. Reboot in Antergos, everything was still working fine.

I started customizing the shell with the gnome-tweak-tool and at some point the buttons in the "power menu" (upper right corner) dissapeared. I changed everything back to the way it was in default (nothing happend) and shut down the PC using the Terminal. After booting Antergos again the power and the settings button were back but Hibernate is still missing. I think there also was a fourth button but I'm not sure.

So what exactly happened - and how can I get the buttons back? (btw. is it possible to add a custom buttons to run scripts like reboot to other operating systems?)

Edit:
I remembered the fourth button, it was "lock session" so this is missing, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the Nvidia driver installed?

If this is true install `nvidia` again like this:

```
pacman -Syy nvidia nvidia-utils nvidia-libgl libvdpau libcl
```

Reboot and check if options shows up.

If you still have a problem run `lg`:

<kbd>alt+r</kbd> -> type `lg` in run command.

You'd have Gnome looking glass, go to extensions and check if `Status Menu Buttons` have some errors.

Comment: I think most chips are AMD but I never checked that. Your last guess was right, the status-menu-button extension had some errors but didn't show the error symbol in the tool. Now everything is visible again. Thanks!